# Create probability matrix based on initial adjacency

Tags: r

This shows my ultimate goal:

[image]

As an initial step, I've taken a stab at it with the code below, but I'm not familiar enough with looping to create the proper probability matrix. Any idea on how to better incorporate adjacency?

```
spatialMatrix <- matrix(data = 1:20, ncol = 5, nrow = 4, byrow = T)
emptyMatrix <- matrix(data = 101, ncol = 4, nrow = 5)

lets <- which(spatialMatrix == 12, arr.ind = TRUE, useNames = F)
for (i in seq_along(1:as.numeric(ncol(emptyMatrix)-lets[,2]))) {
  for (j in seq_along(1:as.numeric(nrow(emptyMatrix)-lets[,1]))) {
    emptyMatrix[lets[,1], lets[,2]] <- 0
    emptyMatrix[lets[,1], lets[,2]+i] <- 0.4
    emptyMatrix[lets[,1], lets[,2]-i] <- 0.4
    # diagonals
    emptyMatrix[lets[,1]+j, lets[,2]+i] <- 0.4
    emptyMatrix[lets[,1]-j, lets[,2]+i] <- 0.4
    emptyMatrix[lets[,1]+j, lets[,2]-i] <- 0.4
    emptyMatrix[lets[,1]-j, lets[,2]-i] <- 0.4

    emptyMatrix[lets[,1]+j, lets[,2]] <- 0.4
    emptyMatrix[lets[,1]-j, lets[,2]] <- 0.4
  }
```

Comment: How are the probabilities obtained from the spatial matrix?

Comment: Hi John, for this example, I've arbitrarily assigned values and they are not from a distribution. 

Direct neighbours (+1 away from initial element) have a value of 0.4, +2 neighbours have a value of 0.1,  +3 neighbours have a value of 0.05.

Comment: And where is the starting point? Since each will be a direct neighbour to the other.

Comment: is it direct neighbours from the diagonal?? or from the very first element ie (1,1)?

Comment: @Onyambu I've clarified in the example image how I define neighbours (includes diagonals)

Comment: How do you pick that red is my question. Do you randomly select it?

Comment: To have a concrete starting point to work on the example, I choose 12 (arbitrary). 

My eventual goal will be to iterate through the range of numbers in the spatial matrix and create the corresponding probability matrices. But for now, I'm trying to figure out how to create the initial example probability matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a base r function: I will also select the element [3,2] Thus subtract 3 from the rows and then subtract 2 from the columns:

```
sm <- matrix(data = 1:20, ncol = 5, nrow = 4, byrow = T)
fun <- function(z)sapply(z,function(x)ifelse(x==0,0,switch(x,0.4,0.1,0.05)))
apply(pmax(abs(row(sm)-3),abs(col(sm)-2)),2,fun)
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,]  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1 0.05
 [2,]  0.4  0.4  0.4  0.1 0.05
 [3,]  0.4  0.0  0.4  0.1 0.05
 [4,]  0.4  0.4  0.4  0.1 0.05
```

Hope this helps
More compact way of even writing the `fun` function above will be:

```
 fun <- function(z)sapply(as.character(z),switch,'0'=0,'1'=0.4,'2'=0.1,'3'=0.05)
```

This code creates the matrices of rows and columns from the spatial Matrix given, it then compares the two taking the maximum, then assigns the probability depending on the maximum value obtained